# Why is the sum of squares within treatments referred to as the sum of squares due to error? (single factor ANOVA)

Tags: anova

compared to the sum of squares among treatments, why is within treatments variation attributed exclusively to error?

Comment: Not clear. Best way is to describe your problem mathematically.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at what ANOVA is doing and why it's called analysis of *variance* when, really, we are trying to compare means, not variances.

First, the sum of squares is a measure of spread from a central point.

Second, let's say we have 3 groups (A, B and C) and our dependent variable is measure on subjects (such as people) within each of those groups. The subjects in group A will not all be identical, nor will the subjects in group B or group C. The amount of variation within a group is "sum of squares within" (SSW). However, you hope that groups A, B and C differ from each other by "enough". So you can also look at how different the sums of squares are across groups. This is "sum of squares between" (SSB).

Your model is that the dependent variable "depends" (in some sense) on the group. Any variation that is not accounted for by your model is "error" - stuff your model didn't account for.  SSB is what your model accounted for; SSW is what your model did *not* account for, or, error.